# Use a float number as a step size in function plot

Tags: python, typeerror

I want to plot a function for `0.975 ≤ x ≤ 1.044 with step size 0.0001` and wonder how I can use a float number as step size?

The function I want to plot is `y=−1+7x−21x2 +35x3 −35x4 +21x5 −7x6 +x7` and I have computed the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.975, 1.044, 0.0001)

# calculate y for each element of x
y = x**7 - 7*x**6 + 21*x**5 - 35*x**4 + 35*x**3 - 21*x**2 + 7*x -1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

The code works fine if I replace the step size value to a int instead of a float, but when I use 0.0001 I get the error below. Is there someway I can fix this?

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 117, in linspace
num = operator.index(num)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/idalundmark/Desktop/Programmeringsteknik för matematiker (Labb)/Avklarade labbar/untitled0.py", line 13, in <module>
    x = np.linspace(0.975, 1.044, 0.0001)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in linspace

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 119, in linspace
    raise TypeError(

TypeError: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

Comment: 3rd parameter of `np.linspace()` must be integer, it specifies the number of samples, not the step size. use `np.arange()` instead

Comment: Oh, thank you @AcaNg! My mistake, this works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy.linespace()` the third parameter indicates the number of samples to generate. (Default it is 50) This could be a non-negative integer value. For more information, you can refer to the official [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

As @AcaNg suggested in the comments, you can use `numpy.arrange()` instead. This is also similar to `linspace`, but uses a step size (instead of the number of samples).

Answer (score 0):

If you do as shown [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) and below, the problem will be solved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = (1.044 - 0.975) / 0.0001

x = np.linspace(0.975, 1.044, num=int(N), endpoint= True)

# calculate y for each element of x
y = x**7 - 7*x**6 + 21*x**5 - 35*x**4 + 35*x**3 - 21*x**2 + 7*x -1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```